# regarding module 'tensorflow.python.platform.build_info' has no attribute 'cudnn_version_number'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I tried to print out the cudnn information from tensorflow as follows

```
from tensorflow.python.platform import build_info as tf_build_info
print(tf_build_info.cudnn_version_number)
```

However, its output is, what's the reason for this error?

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-439c29a4890a> in <module>
----> 1 print(tf_build_info.cudnn_version_number)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.platform.build_info' has no attribute 'cudnn_version_number'
```

Comment: Seems like you are trying to get the cuda or cudnn version, but you may have install  tensorflow CPU version,,,  you may need to install tensorflow with gpu support , for ex: "pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.2.0",   tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu are different installations(before tf2.0). If you have a correctly configured cuda and cudnn, then install tensorflow-gpu, it will auto pick up cuda and cudnn configuration.

Answer (score 3):

using python 3.6, tf 2.5 cuda 11.2 cudnn 8.2. win10 Laptop with Geforce MX150 card:

```py
from tensorflow.python.platform import build_info as tf_build_info
print("cudnn_version",tf_build_info.build_info['cudnn_version'])
 > cudnn_version 64_8 
print("cuda_version",tf_build_info.build_info['cuda_version'])
 > cuda_version 64_112
```

Answer (score 1):

As of TensorFlow 2.4.1, We can use `tensorflow.python.platform.build_info` to get information on which CUDA, cuDNN the binary was built against.

```
>>> import tensorflow
>>> print(tensorflow.__version__)
'2.4.1'
>>> import tensorflow.python.platform.build_info as build
>>> print(build.build_info)
OrderedDict([('cpu_compiler', '/usr/bin/gcc-5'), ('cuda_compute_capabilities', ['sm_35', 'sm_50', 'sm_60', 'sm_70', 'sm_75', 'compute_80']), ('cuda_version', '11.0'), ('cudnn_version', '8'), ('is_cuda_build', True), ('is_rocm_build', False)])
```

The `build.build_info` is an OrderedDict. So to get CuDNN and CUDA versions:

```
>>> print(build.build_info['cuda_version'])
11.0
>>> print(build.build_info['cudnn_version'])
8
```

Note: As this is not a public API, things can change in future versions. In previous versions, we could did `from tensorflow.python.platform import build_info as tf_build_info; print(tf_build_info.cuda_version_number)`